# log4net filepath is empty

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, log4net, log4net-appender

Config of my log4net:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ItemsChangeLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="\logs\ItemChangeLogs\itemLog.{date}.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <priority value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ItemsChangeLogFileAppender"/>
</root>
<logger name="ItemsChangeLogger">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ItemsChangeLogFileAppender"/>          
</logger>
```

class:

```
public class LogEvents
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("ItemsChangeLogger");

    public LogEvents()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log.Info("Some message");
    }

    public void Test(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        log.Info("Test");
    }
}
```

I want to read my logs but don't find my file.

In some question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343749/get-log4net-log-file-in-c-sharp)) I use answer but filepath is empty. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read your configuration:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure("log4net.config");
```

This assumes the name of you configuration file is log4net.xml. The log4net.xml file has to be in your bin directory.

The \logs\ItemChangeLogs folder must exist on your file system. I would change that to something like: c:\logs\ItemChangeLogs, so you know log4net will find the dir on your c drive, instead of an other drive.

[log4net configuration documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

I normally configure log4net using an attribute in the `assembly.cs` file like:

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.config in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.exe)
// The config file will be watched for changes.
```

Comment: `log4net` hasn't class `XmlConfigurator`. Ths class in `log4net.Config` and hasn't parametr as string

Comment: sorry, it has to be: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator

Comment: But overloads haven't parametr as string... Maybe it for .net-4.0?

Comment: Have a look at the log4net configuration documentation: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: You can enable log4net debugging: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: I dont know... It may be that it will not work because this class don't use App.config of this project?

Comment: You have to be sure the config file is in de the running/dll directory of project. Try to copy it by hand to test if that works.