# Get the directory of the Log4Net ILog instance

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net

I have a dll, which gets an instance of ILog.

Using this ILog instance, i want to get the directory that the logger is writing to, because I want to create a file with some other info into the same folder.

I tried the following:

```
var fa = _log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders().FirstOrDefault(a => a is RollingFileAppender);
```

For the fileappender, it does not have the *fa.File* option. The options that it shows me are: .DoAppend(), .Name and .Close()

Any ideas how to get the fa.File value? so that I can derive the directory and create my file in that directory?

Comment: I'm not positive, just started playing with log4net myself, but if you're using a FileAppender it only writes a log file into the same directory as the *.exe. You specify the log file name in the AppConfig (or WebConfig if this isn't a winform application) and it creates / writes to a file with that name in the same directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it, based on a post here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343913/475882

I had to specify the type in <>:

```
var fa = _log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders().OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();
```