# How to read log4Net from web.config

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net to perform daily logging. 

I realize that log4net doesn't support deleting old files in this fashion.

I am trying to write my own method to accomplish this task, however I am no sure how to read the log4net settings from the web.config file.

I've tried:

```
var log4NetData = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net");
```

However I get this as my results:

> The type 'System.Configuration.ConfigXmlElement' exists in both 'System.Configuration.dll' and 'System.dll'

How can I read the log4net node from my web.config?

Comment: That's the compiler telling you it doesn't know which `ConfigXmlElement` you want it to use. You seem to have two, one in each of the specified DLLs. Change the var to be more specific.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.GetSection() returns type object. Is it a different line throwing the exception?

Comment: What settings do you need? You could probably get them from log4net directly without having to read the config.

Comment: Tying to grab the file format for each appender.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343749/get-log4net-log-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: That's what I needed @stuartd!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Log4Net can update the same file always (this way, there is no need to delete it and create another one). 
I'm using log4Net to log always the same file n times in a hour. My configurations:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

app.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>  
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="application.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Our admins want a log files listed by the day.  Which is fine but they only want 30 days of logs.