# Log4net XmlConfigurator Configure issue

Tags: c#, logging, .net-4.0, log4net

I am trying to set the location of my log4net.config file programmaticly in my C# project, using .net 4.0 and v1.2.11 of log4net, like it is defined [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html). It looks straight forward enough but whenever I try to use the XmlConfigurator.Configure methid I get the following error:

> Error 4
>   'log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository,
>   System.IO.Stream)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

This is the line of code that is causing the problem:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\LocatorConfig.xml"));
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.
Anto

Comment: What's the problem here? your code works perfectly ...
anyway if I were you I would try using the Configure() overload that takes a Uri instead ...

Comment: Could you provide the complete code of the function containing this line ?
It might be a syntax error on the preceding line or something like this.

Comment: @Omribitan The problem is that it doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: @Marshall777 The only code before the XmlConfigurator call is the definition of a public class that inherits the interface ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGPFunction

Comment: I still don't know what caused this issue, it still occurs only in this class, but adding a wrapper like suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028375/how-do-you-configure-and-enable-log4net-for-a-stand-alone-class-library-assembly) has helped with my issue.

Comment: @Omribitan Then just copy and paste the whole code file content as it won't be too long. I can't see anything else than a syntax error to justify the compilation error you mentioned.