# How to make Log4Net to read it's related configuration from a wrapper class in its own class library project?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have following requirement.

For simplicity Lets say my solution consists of two projects.

1. A Class library Project wrapping Log4Net Functionality.
2. A MVC web application project as calling app to class library logger methods which in turn should call log4net actual methods.

I wanted to specify log4net config in the class library app.config file or a xml file in this project.

I read the simlar issue at this thread [How do you configure and enable log4net for a stand-alone class library assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028375/how-do-you-configure-and-enable-log4net-for-a-stand-alone-class-library-assembly/1028425#1028425)

But the solution of putting the following two lines in Assembly.info file of my classlibray project didn't work for me.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.Repository("ClassLibrary1")]
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "ClassLibrary1.config", Watch = true)]
```

As Log4Net is unable to find the related configuration.

For records the name of my class library assembly = ClassLibrary1

I am referring this library from my mvc web app project.

Any ideas why the solution2 as in thread [How do you configure and enable log4net for a stand-alone class library assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028375/how-do-you-configure-and-enable-log4net-for-a-stand-alone-class-library-assembly/1028425#1028425)

is not working for me?

**Edit:**

My program flow is like this.

My MVC app starts.

Unity injects a singleton instance of my log4netwrapper through constructor injection successfully.

Then in a action method i make a call to logger through my wrapper. In the wrapper constructor I make the XmlConfigurator.

Please note while calling i am not supplying the fileinfo object as path to read config entry. For that purpose only in my wrapper assembly

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.Repository("ClassLibrary1")] 
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "ClassLibrary1.config", 
                                          Watch = true)].
```

Any solutions here?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [log4net documentation for assembly attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) it says this:

> Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
>   to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to
>   LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly
>   to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging
>   call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
>   certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**

The thing is, when you do this in your MVC project startup, the assembly attributes **are** in an external assembly, ClassLibrary1.

If you use `XmlConfigurator.Configure(...)` as in the answer you linked to, it will work.

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting your exact steps here.

Comment: My program flow is like this. my mvc app starts. unity injects a singleton instance of my log4netwrapper through constructor injection succesfully. then in a action method i make a call to logger through my wrapper. in the wrapper constructor i make the xmlconfigurator. Please note while calling i am not supplying the fileinfo object as path to read config entry. For that purpose only in my wrapper assembly [assembly: log4net.Config.Repository("ClassLibrary1")]
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "ClassLibrary1.config", Watch = true)].  Any solutions here?