# When you reference library how to copy to TargetDir not only .dll but also .config

Tags: c#, reference, config, solution, class-library

I have an additional config file for my library. I use it to config log4net. So library can configure log4net. I add reference to the library to another project in my solution and i need to make VS copy not only .dll file, but also .config file. How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: .NET class libraries generally don't have .config files.  [Tell me more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file)

Comment: How about setup your own Nuget server and create packages for these library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Micky pointed out assemblies don't have config files, but you could use "Add existing file" and select "Add as Link" and then set "Copy To Output Directory" To "Copy always" this way the file should be copied to the output directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the configuration section for log4net in the `app.config` file of the main project you are referencing the library...

You can also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028375/how-do-you-configure-and-enable-log4net-for-a-stand-alone-class-library-assembly)...

Comment: and if i will change library config?

Comment: Then you change it in the app.config?

Comment: Rather than having log4net config sections in multiple libraries, create one log4net config file and include it in app.config as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480538/use-xml-includes-or-config-references-in-app-config-to-include-other-config-file)

Comment: That is a lot to ask, if it were possible to add relative link to library config from app config, that would be nice though.

Comment: You can load a configsection from a separate file, I just posted the link in the previous comment. Be careful though, you can include specific config sections, not entire config files

Comment: You approach is good, but in my very special case, i need it for test app for VS visualizer, i will use my approach. Thanks. Anyway +1.